# Euler Characteristic in dimension four

Tags: riemannian-geometry

My doubt is simple:

> How can I prove that in dimension 4, the Euler Characteristic of a Riemannian Manifold is given by
>   $$\chi(M^4)=\frac{1}{8\pi^2}\int\limits_{M^4}\left(|W|^2+\frac{R^2}{24}-\frac{1}{2}|\stackrel{\circ}{Ric}|^2\right)\,d\mu$$

I know that the Rimannian curvature tensor can decompose into irreducilble components:
$$Rm=\frac{R}{24}g\circ g+\stackrel{\circ}{Ric}\circ g+W$$

where $``\circ"$ is the classical Kulkarni-Nomizu product

Someone can help me with this? thanks

Comment: this won't help with your question, but that graphic on your website is awesome!

Comment: You probably want to check out the references in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem

Comment: I did it, later I can put the prove here...